# React efficiency using CSS class or render state change?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, performance

This is more of a React performance question.

My question would be, adding/removing a CSS classname (I.e. Adding "show" class name) to an element is better via **DOM manipulation** or **state change**? I do find that direct DOM manipulation "classList" is definitely faster when the targeted DOM element is already known.

A snippet would be:

```
const menuRef= React.createRef();

constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   /*if I am to use state*/
   //this.state = {isMenuShown: false}
}

_toggleShow = () => {
   //Changing states?
   /* this.setState({isMenuShown: !this.state.isMenuShown}); */
   if(this.menuRef.current) {
     if(!this.menuRef.current.classList.contains("show")) {
       this.menuRef.current.classList.add("show");
     }
     else {
       this.menuRef.current.classList.remove("show");
     }
   }  
}

render() {
  let ulClassName = "";
  /* If I am to use state*/
  //ulClassName = this.state.isMenuShown ? "show":"";
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <nav onClick={this._toggleShow)>
        <ul ref={this.menuRef} className={ulClassName}>
          <li>Sample 1</li>
          <li>Sample 2</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <style jsx>{`
       ul {
          display: none;
       }
       ul.show {
          display: block;
          //I can add CSS @keyframes to display
          //Inner child elements relies on ".show" too for responsive design.
       }
     `}</style>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

}

I know that states are the advised way to go, but scenario above justifies(at least to me) that DOM manipulation is better when CSS are heavily relied on. Take example for the CSS usage are:

- Inner child responsive designs.
- Animation using CSS @keyframes

What would you really use or how does one over come this? In future did DOM manipulation actually create a problem for anyone?

Comment: Let React handle this for you as the reconciliation engine does all the heavy lifting to optimize updates. https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html. I'd recommend reading up on refs and when to use them. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I had read it and wow this is really really the answer I need. Now I get why states are the way to go and will go through the whole React Advanced section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe directly manipulating DOM elements within react is an anti pattern. It's doable, but not recommended.

As a side note, I use a node module named `classnames` to help toggle rendered elements that is used right on the `className` prop. It does this by handling the adding or removing of classes based on logic you provide.

Comment: Ah that's a nice add on to classnames. I had give thoughts to the anti-pattern, but re-rendering cause a lot of over head to rewrite to the browser.